# combo box autocomplete

Tags: gwt, combobox

Is there anyway to have the autocomplete for a combo box to start from anywhere in the text, let me give you an example. If I have someone named john smith in the combobox if I start with the letter 'j' it pulls up john smith but less say I want to start with the letter 's' to search for his last name, is that possible, if so does anyone have code or a link to code that does this.

Comment: Check http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtchosen/ is based on GQuery

Answer (score 12):

Have you looked at [`SuggestBox`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html)? The [`MultiWordSuggestOracle`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MultiWordSuggestOracle.html) that feeds the data to the suggest box seems to do exactly what you want - see the javadocs for usage and examples.

*Update:* Here's a rather nice example of customizing GWT's `SuggestBox` to look like the one on Facebook: http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/creating_a_facebook_style_autocomplete Be sure to follow all the links in that tutorial, as they contain a lot of info about using the `SuggestBox`.

Answer (score 3):

I been have any problems with AdvancedComboBoxExample sencha
http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:advancedcombobox

I found in this link http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?222543-CRTL-C-triggers-a-reload-of-data-in-Combobox the response for my problem.

I had to make some adjustments to my code. Below is the code for those who need it.

ComboBox ajax without paging:

```java
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.*;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.store.ListStore;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.ComboBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class AjaxComboBox<T extends ModelData> extends ComboBox<T> {

    public AjaxComboBox() {
    }

    public interface GetDataCallback<T> {

        void getData(String query, AsyncCallback<List<T>> dataCallback);
    }

    public AjaxComboBox(final String displayField, final int minChars, final GetDataCallback<T> getDataCallback) {
        final RpcProxy<ListLoadResult<T>> proxy = new RpcProxy<ListLoadResult<T>>() {

            @Override
            protected void load(final Object loadConfig, final AsyncCallback<ListLoadResult<T>> callback) {
                ListLoadConfig load = (ListLoadConfig) loadConfig;
                final Map<String, Object> properties = load.getProperties();

                getDataCallback.getData((String) properties.get("query"), new AsyncCallback<List<T>>() {

                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        caught.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    public void onSuccess(List<T> result) {
                        callback.onSuccess(new BaseListLoadResult<T>(result));
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        final BaseListLoader<ListLoadResult<T>> loader = new BaseListLoader<ListLoadResult<T>>(proxy);
        final ListStore<T> store = new ListStore<T>(loader);
        setFieldLabel(displayField);
        setStore(store);
        setHideTrigger(true);
        setMinChars(minChars);
        setWidth(300);
    }

}
```

ComboBox lazy with paging

```java
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.*;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.Listener;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.store.ListStore;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.ComboBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import java.util.Map;

public class ComboBoxLazy<T extends ModelData> extends ComboBox<T> {

    public interface GetPagingDataCallback<T> {

        void getData(String query, PagingLoadConfig loadConfig,
                AsyncCallback<PagingLoadResult<T>> dataCallback);
    }

    public ComboBoxLazy(final String displayField, final int minChars,
            final GetPagingDataCallback<T> getDataCallback) {


        final RpcProxy<PagingLoadResult<T>> proxy = new RpcProxy<PagingLoadResult<T>>() {

            @Override
            protected void load(Object loadConfig,
                    final AsyncCallback<PagingLoadResult<T>> callback) {
                final Map<String, Object> properties = ((PagingLoadConfig) loadConfig).getProperties();
                getDataCallback.getData((String) properties.get("query"),
                        ((PagingLoadConfig) loadConfig),
                        new AsyncCallback<PagingLoadResult<T>>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(
                                    final PagingLoadResult<T> result) {
                                callback.onSuccess(result);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                                callback.onFailure(caught);
                            }
                        });
            }
        };


        ModelReader reader = new ModelReader();
        final BasePagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<T>> loader = new BasePagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<T>>(
                proxy, reader);
        loader.addListener(Loader.BeforeLoad, new Listener<LoadEvent>() {

            public void handleEvent(LoadEvent be) {
                be.<ModelData>getConfig().set("start",
                        be.<ModelData>getConfig().get("offset"));
            }
        });

        setFieldLabel(displayField);
        final ListStore<T> store = new ListStore<T>(loader);
        setStore(store);
        setHideTrigger(true);
        setMinChars(minChars);
        setPageSize(10);
        setWidth(300);
    }

}
```

Class Test

```java
import br.ueg.escala.client.view.ConversorBeanModel;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.*;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.SelectionChangedEvent;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.SelectionChangedListener;

import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.LayoutContainer;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.VerticalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import java.util.List;
public class ComboBoxTest extends LayoutContainer {

   @Override
    protected void onRender(Element parent, int index) {
        super.onRender(parent, index);
        criarComboBox();
        criarComboBoxLazy();
    }

    private void criarComboBox() {

        final AjaxComboBox<BeanModel> combo = new AjaxComboBox<BeanModel>("name", 3, new AjaxComboBox.GetDataCallback<BeanModel>() {

            public void getData(String query, final AsyncCallback<List<BeanModel>> dataCallback) {
                servico.loadLike(query, new AsyncCallback<List<Person>>() {

                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        caught.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    public void onSuccess(List<Person> result) {
                        List<BeanModel> dados = ConversorBeanModel.getListBeanModel(result);
                        dataCallback.onSuccess(dados);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        combo.addSelectionChangedListener(new SelectionChangedListener<BeanModel>() {

            @Override
            public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent<BeanModel> se) {
                BeanModel bm = combo.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                Person p = bm.getBean();
                combo.setValue(bm);

                try {
                    combo.setValue(bm);
                    combo.setRawValue(p.getName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        combo.setItemSelector("div.search-item");
        combo.setTemplate(getTemplate());

        addText("Any text");
        add(combo);
    }

    private void criarComboBoxLazy() {
        String field = "name";
        final ComboBoxLazy<BeanModel> comboLazy = new ComboBoxLazy<BeanModel>(field, 3, new                     ComboBoxLazy.GetPagingDataCallback<BeanModel>() {

            public void getData(String query, PagingLoadConfig loadConfig, final AsyncCallback<PagingLoadResult<BeanModel>> dataCallback) {
                final PagingLoadConfig load = (PagingLoadConfig) loadConfig;

                servico.loadLike(load, new Person(), "name", query, new AsyncCallback<List>() {

                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        caught.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    public void onSuccess(List result) {
                        PagingLoadResult<BeanModel> dados = ConversorBeanModel.getPagingLoadResultBeanModel(result, load);
                        dataCallback.onSuccess(dados);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        comboLazy.addSelectionChangedListener(new SelectionChangedListener<BeanModel>() {

            @Override
            public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent<BeanModel> se) {
                BeanModel bm = comboLazy.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                Person p = bm.getBean();
                comboLazy.setValue(bm);

                try {
                    comboLazy.setValue(bm);
                    comboLazy.setRawValue(p.getName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        comboLazy.setItemSelector("div.search-item");
        comboLazy.setTemplate(getTemplate());

        VerticalPanel vp2 = new VerticalPanel();
        vp2.setSpacing(10);
        vp2.addText("<span class='text'><b>Combo lazy</span>");
        vp2.add(comboLazy);
        add(vp2);
    }

    private native String getTemplate() /*-{
    return [ '<tpl for="."><div class="search-item">',
    ' <h3> <span> Name:</span> <span style="font-weight:normal;">{name}</span> ',
    ' <span> - Last name:</span> <span style="font-weight: normal">{lastName}</span></h3>', '</div></tpl>'].join("");
    }-*/;

}
```

Application.css:

```css
.searchItem {
  font: normal 11px tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
  white-space: normal;
  color: #555;
}

.searchItem h3 {
  display: block;
  font: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #222;
}

.searchItem h3 span {
  float: right;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  clear: none;
}
```

Code server

```java
public List loadLike(PagingLoadConfig config, Person classe, String field, String query) {
    List<Person> list = null;
    try {
        List listEntity = genericoBC.loadLike(config.getOffset(), config.getLimit(), field, query, classe.getClass());
        list = clone(listEntity);

        final int totalCount = genericoBC.contarRegistros(classe.getClass());
        config.setLimit(totalCount);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tratarExcecao("", e);
    }
    return list;
}

public List<Person> loadLike(String query) {
    List<Person> list = null;
    try {
        List<Person> listEntity = genericoBC.loadLike(query);
        list = clone(listEntity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tratarExcecao("Error:genericoBC.loadLike(query)", e);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override the method  **boolean isFiltered(ModelData record, String property)** of the **ListStore** of the combobox.The method body will be following:

```
if (filterBeginsWith != null && property != null) {
    Object o = record.get(property);
    if (o != null) {
        if (!o.toString().toLowerCase().contains(filterBeginsWith.toLowerCase())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
if (filters != null) {
    for (StoreFilter filter : filters) {
        boolean result = filter.select(this, record, record, property);
        if (!result) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for GXT 3.0.

First, create an instance of the overridden ListStore class like this:

```
  public static class MyListStore extends ListStore<Course>{
  private String userText="";
  public MyListStore(ModelKeyProvider<Course> k){ 
    super(k); 
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean isFilteredOut(Course item) {
    boolean result = false;
    if(item.getTitle()!=null && 
      !item.getTitle().toUpperCase().contains(userText.toUpperCase())){
      result = true;
    }
    return result;
  }
  public void setUserText(String t){ userText = t; }
}
```

In this case, I had a Course model class that had the course title (a string) as the label provider for the combobox.  So in your overridden class, do similar: use your specific model (the type of this instance of the combobox) in place of 'Course' in the code above.

Next, create an instance of this store for use by the combobox:

```
  private MyListStore courses ;
```

Next, make sure you initialize the combobox appropriately with this.  In my case, I used uibinder, so my initializer is this:

```
  @UiFactory
  ListStore<Course> createListStore() {
    courses = new MyListStore(courseProps.key());
    return courses;
  }
```

The relevant uibinder snippets:

```
  <ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.LabelProvider" field="titles"/>
  <ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.ListStore" field="courses"/>
  ...
  <form:ComboBox ui:field="classTitle" store="{courses}" labelProvider="{titles}"
        allowBlank="false" forceSelection="true" triggerAction="ALL" width="200" />
```

Of course, the linkage into your bound java class:

```
  @UiField ComboBox<Course> classTitle;
```

And, finally, make sure you handle the keyup event from the combobox input:

```
classTitle.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler(){
  @Override
  public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
    courses.setUserText(classTitle.getText());
  }
});
```

This worked perfectly (first time!).